# Vim line completion with external file

Tags: vim

Can line completion <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> be used to show line completions from a specific external file instead of "only" from the current buffer?
Something like dictionaries, but for lines.

Update:

To test I did following:

- created a file `tt.txt` with some test lines
- placed the file in D:\t1\ (I'm on windows)
- included the file with `:set path+=D:\\t1\\tt.txt`
- `:set complete ?` returns `complete =.,w,b,u,t,i`
- `:set path ?` returns `path=.,,,D:\t1\tt.txt`
- `checkpath` returns: All included files were found
- typing a line which should be completed with the matching content from tt.txt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> returns pattern not found

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried reading `:help ins-completion`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve what you want is with a custom complete-function. See `help complete-functions` for the (very useful!) documentation. Here's my attempt at a solution:

First you need a separate function to silently grep a file for a string (if you just call the naked `vimgrep` function you will get an ugly error if there are no matches).

```
function! SilentFileGrep( leader, file )
    try
        exe 'vimgrep /^\s*' . a:leader . '.*/j ' . a:file
    catch /.*/
        echo "no matches"
    endtry
endfunction
```

Now, here's your completion function. Note that the path to the file you want to search is hard-coded in here, but you could change it to use a variable if you so wish. We call `SilentFileGrep()`, which dumps the results in the quickfix list. Then we extract the results from the qflist (trimming the leading whitespace) and clear the qflist before returning the results.

```
function! LineCompleteFromFile(findstart,base)
    if a:findstart
        " column to begin searching from (first non-whitespace column):
        return match(getline("."),'\S')
    else
        " grep the file and build list of results:
        let path = <path_to_file>
        call SilentFileGrep( a:base, path )
        let matches = []
        for thismatch in getqflist()
            " trim leading whitespace
            call add(matches, matchstr(thismatch.text,'\S.*'))
        endfor
        call setqflist([])
        return matches
    endif
endfunction
```

To use this function, you need to set the `completefunc` option to point at it:

```
set completefunc=LineCompleteFromFile
```

Then you can use `<C-X><C-U>` to invoke the completion, which you could easily map to `<C-X><C-L>`.

This seems to work pretty well for me, but it is not exhaustively tested.

Comment: I rewrote this plugin (and improved in my opinion) this a bit into an independent [plugin](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=5617) and also available as a standard vim plugin on https://gitlab.com/mcepl/vim-files-complete

Answer (score 2):

In Vim help for line completion it's written that it only works for loaded buffers. As a workaround, you may open your "dictionary" file in another buffer and Vim will suggest lines from this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

- `'path'` is supposed to be a list of directories so (assuming that's the correct syntax on Windows) `:set path+=D:\\t1\\tt.txt` should be `:set path+=D:\\t1\\` or  `:set path+=D:\\t1`.
- The `i` in `'complete'` means that the completion candidates are chosen from *current and **included** files*. You must *include* a file for completion to work: it won't if you don't explicitly include that file.

  Say that you have created `~/test/testfile` with this single line:

  ```
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  ```

  You add it to Vim's `'path'` with:

  ```
  :set path+=~/test
  ```

  To use it as completion source in a C++ file you would do:

  ```
  #include <testfile>
  ```

  and be able to do:

  ```
  lore<C-x><C-f>
  ```

  to get:

  ```
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  ```

As far as I know, it doesn't work with languages that don't have an `include` mechanism like C or C++ so you can forget about it for Markdown, JavaScript, plain text or, if my tests are any indication, even PHP which does have `include`.

If you want a more generic mechanism, just add that file to the arglist: it will automatically be used as a completion source:

```
:argadd ~/test/testfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
:set dictionary=<some file>
```

then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to complete from `<some file`>

See

```
:help ins-completion
```

for more info.

Comment: The question is about whole-line completion (`CTRL-X CTRL-L`). `'dictionary'` is for completing words, that is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

As @black_wizard points out, the other file must be loaded in a buffer. With `set hidden`, you can use the following to load another file and return to the previous buffer:

```
command! -nargs=? XL silent edit <args> | silent bprevious
```

To load `tt.txt` into another buffer and return to the previous one:

```
:XL tt.txt
```